# IE 7 ul li nesting and positioning - the top end does not match up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Here's the link to the page:
http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/

The positioning of the

tags under the ul#menu appears to be skewed on IE7. I have put borders on the UL (#f00) and LI (#0f0) items to clarify.

IN Firefox, the LI items nest properly to the top of the UL, however on IE the LI nests to the top of the div#menubar rather than the ul#menu under it.

The DOM tree is like this:

```
<div id="menubar" class="grid_16 alpha omega">
     <ul id="menu">
          <li style="margin-left:0px;"><a href="/" title="homepage">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/about">about me</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/listings">featured listings</a>   
               <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                         <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/area-map">on a map</a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/mls-search">MLS&reg; search</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/resources">resources</a>
               <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                         <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/for-buyers">for buyers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/for-sellers">for sellers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/pre-sale-assignment">pre-sale / assignment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/useful-links">useful links</a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/blog">blog</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/contact">contact me</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Pretty standard div>ul>li menu structure, with optional submenus under each

as a ul.submenu>li structure.

I tried putting a "float:left;" to the #menu li node, and that did solve the positioning; however then I don't have a nice centre aligned menu - everything goes to the left on the menu.

Here's the current css revolving around this (note that I'm using 960 grid, and also the reset.css and text.css file that comes with it).

```
#menubar {
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu {
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:0px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#menu li {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style:none;
    z-index: 25;
    position: relative !important;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;

}

#menu li a:link, #menu li a:visited {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
}

#menu li a:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    color:#fff;
}

.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    display: block;
    background-color:#906117;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:30;
}

#menu li:hover .submenu {
    left: 0px;
}

.submenu li {
    text-align: left !important;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding: 3px 0px 5px 0px !important;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 35;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.submenu li:hover {
    background-color: #f79c10;
}

.submenu li a:link, .submenu li a:visited {
    color:#fff !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding:3px 10px 5px 10px !important;
    z-index: 40;

}

.submenu li a:hover, .submenu li a:active {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 ignores margins when ul elements have a relative position. You can fix this by removing the margin in your ul#menu styles and add that value back in the parent div#menubar.

This will give you the same layout result, but will resolve the IE7 margin/relative bug.

Comment: "IE7 ignores margins when ul elements have a relative position" - I did NOT know that, and how ridiculous is such rule.. dear lord do I ever hate IE